# How to avoide uninitialized variable in SAS

Tags: sas

```
DATA M.PROV; 
SET M.ORIG_0002;
BY 'PROVIDER ID'n;
IF FIRST.'PROVIDER ID'n THEN OUTPUT M.PROV;
RUN;
```

When I run this code the im getting
NOTE: Variable 'FIRST.''PROVIDER ID''n'n is uninitialized.

How can I fix could you please help

Comment: I think you have to check if 'PROVIDER ID' exists in FIRST  at the beginning of the IF condition,  IF EXISTS(FIRST, 'PROVIDER ID')

Comment: I used this
IF exists(FIRST.'PROVIDER ID'n) THEN OUTPUT M.PROV;
getting ERROR 68-185: The function EXISTS is unknown, or cannot be accessed.

Comment: Go back to your data import stage. Add the option `options validvarname=v7;` to before your import. Then your data set will be imported with cleaner variable names so you don't have these issues, such as PROVIDER_ID. The variable labels will be "Provider ID" so you can easily display the clean name if you'd like as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `first.` in quotes as well:

`'first.provider id'n`

[SAS Documentation - Example: Specify the FIRST. and LAST. BY Variables as Name Literals](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lepg/p0ibybzsojk9u8n17a3k3vgflzzf.htm#p0pibnmz4ebkb0n1mo5uejpk0ft8)

Comment: IF EXISTS('FIRST.PROVIDER ID') THEN OUTPUT M.PROV;
ERROR 68-185: The function EXISTS is unknown, or cannot be accessed. Getting same error

Comment: You do not need to use that function; it's invalid in a data step. Your code will work fine if you change your if statement to `if 'first.provider id'n`.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked